# unable to communicate between background and content listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

making a dev tool chrome extension in svelte. im currently communicating with the background service worker from my extension but am having no luck communicating between the background and content script. I cant figure out why. any help would be greatly appreciated.

receiving this error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

### App.svelte

```
  //creates connection with background
  const background = runtime.connect();

  onMount(() => {
    //sends message to background
    background.postMessage({
      type: "hello",
    });
    console.log("message posted");
  });
```

### background.js

```
console.log('in the background!')

//create listener at runtime
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  console.log('in onConnect listener')
  //make listener function to accept messages from front end and post messages 
  const extensionListener = function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('in extension listener')
    console.log('message:', message)
  
    if (message.type === 'hello') {
      // console.log('message type hello received in background');
      // chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
      //   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: 'greetings' });
      // });
      port.postMessage({
        type: 'greetings',
      });
    }
  };
  // create listener invoking function to hear messages sent from the DevTools page
  port.onMessage.addListener(extensionListener);
});
```

### content.js

```
console.log('chrome runtime onmessage', chrome.runtime)
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message) {
    console.log('this is message in content script', message)
    if (message.type === "hello")
      // sendRootNodeToExtension('returnRootComponent');
      console.log(message.type)
  }
);
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Sveltechron",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Browser devtools extension for debugging Svelte applications.",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "background", "nativeMessaging", "scripting"],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["*"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "resources": ["svelte-listener/src/", "svelte-listener/src/index.js", "svelte-listener/src/listener.js", "svelte-listener/src/profiler.js", "svelte-listener/src/svelte.js"]
  }],
  "background": {
    "type": "module",
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "run_at": "document_start" 
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtools/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/16.png",
    "32": "images/32.png",
    "48": "images/48.png",
    "128": "images/128.png"
  }
}
```

ive tried communcating directly between extension and content script. directly between background and content. ive only been able to communicate with background and extension. when i introduce the content script into this 3 way connection it greaks the connection between background and extension and fails to receive any messages.

Comment: You're incorrectly mixing two types of messaging. To send to chrome.runtime.onMessage you need chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id. Depending on the workflow there may be more solutions e.g. [a port relay](/a/72902614). There is also chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval that doesn't require content scripts. P.S. You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.